# Mysterious artist: LaptopPlugins

Tags: unknown-performer, release

The song "Home Radio" has no lyrics on MusixMatch, so I decided to contribute them. I looked online for them, to no avail. I tried to transcribe them myself, but many lines were cryptic or unintelligible.

I decided to do further research. The song featured **Boots** and **Sosa**. I found [info on Boots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boots_(musician)), but I could not find anything for both LaptopPlugins and Sosa, aside from iTunes/Amazon/Spotify pages which simply contained related songs.

But then, I found this on the album page in iTunes of [Far Rock Away - EP](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/far-rock-away-ep/id1025313160):

[image: Parkwood Entertainment LLC]

Parkwood Entertainment has [a wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkwood_Entertainment). I even found [a twitter page](https://twitter.com/parkwood_ent). Beyoncé founded the company. The twitter page linked to a dead website, [parkwoodentertainment.com](http://parkwoodentertainment.com/). Looking closer, I realized that the last post on the twitter page was on January 27, 2014. However, the song was released in 2015. Even stranger, they seem to have created [the music video for "Formation"](https://youtu.be/LrCHz1gwzTo) in 2016 (as you can see at the very end of the video)!

Can anybody find more information on LaptopPlugins, Sosa or Parkwood Entertainment?

Comment: [Laptopplugins twitter page](https://twitter.com/laptopplugins).  And: [Laptopplugins releases at Evolution records](http://highlyevolving.com/Artist/4210053/LaptopPlugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptop plugins has a [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/laptopplugins)   (Denzel Freeman), also discog at [Evolving Records](http://highlyevolving.com/Artist/4210053/LaptopPlugins)

Wikipedia article on [Chief Keef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Keef) states he also goes by "Sosa", although the music credits don't seem to cross-refer to the music you mention.But Boots, from his wikipedia entry seems to do a lot of collaborations, and not all are in the spotlight.

Parkwood entertainment also has [Linkedin page](https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/6323600/?pathWildcard=6323600), [FB page](https://www.facebook.com/ParkwoodEntertainment/)